# questions/tagged/botframework LUIS

Tags: azure-sql-database, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am planning to build a similar chatbot built by Microsoft team for a super mall in china (https://microsoft.github.io/techcasestudies/bot%20framework/2017/06/21/CaaP-SuperBrandMall.html), I have below requirement :I am using visual studio 5 for Bot Framework.

1. I want to get the details of different clothes available in the store
2. I want to fetch the data from Azure SQL ( Already have data in csv format)
3. I want to connect LUIS too
4. Integration with Skype

I have the following queries:

1. Which type of dialog is used here? Can I do it with only FormFlow dialog?
2. Integration of Bot framework with Azure SQL( Mainly fetching the details of location of clothes for particular ocassion,gender,brand in mall)
3. What modification is required in Model folder in bot framework?
4. Integration of LUIS

Please help me with this if anybody can suggest/add.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked into these samples: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples which demonstrate how to use the dialogs or integrate LUIS etc.

Comment: I agree with Elletlar, you seem not to have tried anything, if you just want to know how to achieve your requirements: integrate LUIS with bot application and operate Azure SQL database, you can refer to my reply. If you have problems with integration of LUIS and Azure SQL etc while you build your bot application, please check the link that Elletlar provided to describe and post the specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

> Which type of dialog is used here? Can I do it with only FormFlow dialog?

[FormFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) suits for handling and managing a guided conversation, based upon the specified guidelines (or collecting information from the user).

Based on your scenario and requirements, your bot would have more complex logic, integrate with LUIS service *(recognize user intent and then do different operations based on what user said)* and perform database etc, I recommend using [dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-dialogs?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) to manage conversation flow, which would be more flexible.

> Integration of LUIS and Integration of Bot framework with Azure SQL

In your bot application, you can create&use LuisDialog to integrate with a LUIS.ai application easily, which could help detect what a user wants to do by identifying their intent, and then you can get the matching **entities** from `LuisResult` within intent handler method in LuisDialog.

After you know user intent and the matching **entities**, you can call different methods or child dialogs to do different business logic or operate database to get location, stores or products etc details.

***Note:***

- [LUIS Bot Sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/intelligence-LUIS)
- [Best practices of building LUIS app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-concept-best-practices)